# 401 error when issuing curl command on Fortinet's FortiNAC API URL

Tags: api, curl

On both Linux and Windows, I cannot get the following curl command to give me an expected JSON output back back from Fortinet's FortiNAC 8.7.

```
curl -k --location --request GET 'https://192.168.0.110:8443/api/v2/host' -H 'Authorization: Bearer my-API-key-here'
```

I get the following 401 unauthorized error from Tomcat.

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.76 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - Unauthorized</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Unauthorized</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.76</h3></body></html>
```

I am following the example in the documentation, and I am pretty sure that I set up the API admin profile, API user, and token correctly.

The [FortiNAC 8.7 API documentation](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortinac/8.7.0/rest-api-v2) looks pretty straight forward, so not sure what I might be missing. This also works ok on Fortinet Fortigate firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

This problem turned out to be a problem with the Apache Tomcat stack.

Running this on another known good host gave a 200 OK response.